# django foreign key agrregates with a where clause on them

Tags: django, foreign-keys, aggregate

I am annotating my queryset in Django, using values from another table mapping as so.

```
    lw_list = lw_list.annotate(count_mapping=Count('mapping'))
```

(lw objects have a one to many relationship with the mapping objects)

So now each object in my lw list has a count of related mapping objects.
My mapping objects have a boolean field 'pass_fail'

Is it possible to put a where clause on the mapping table, so that the aggreagte only counts mapping objects that have a "pass_fail" value set to true?

How do you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this can be done using Django's ORM as of now -- here's [a pretty active ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11305) about what you want, and here's [a pretty hackish workaround](http://voteruniverse.com/Members/jlantz/blog/conditional-aggregates-in-django) suggested by someone in there. I'd say your best bet would be to use raw SQL for now.

Comment: OK, thanks, I have seen a few hacky workarounds posted. I had assumed it might be a bit easier.